# Need help doing some tricky log-in using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have no idea how to direct/target the result of this login form post to a specific page on my site, where an Iframe will control the session. Yes, I could just use a standard Iframe to show the remote site's login form to the user, but I'd like to use my own if at all possible.

I'm going to add a concrete example:

My page with the login form is here:
clients.connectedmanagement.com/login.html

You will see that the current form calls a remote site, as follows:

After the user submits their username/password into the form on login.html, I need them taken to the following page on my site, with the results shown in an iframe:
clients.connectedmanagement.com/newpage.html

Right now, newpage.html simply has an Iframe. How can I get the resulting https://rwa.rentmanager.com page to display in the iframe located on newpage.html, after a user submits the current login form on login.html?

Comment: You can simply use the `target` attribute to get the result of a form submission displayed inside of an iframe. (Whether or not the remote site will “play ball”, or f.e. has taken measures to avoid being displayed within an iframe on another domain, is a different matter …)

Answer (score 1):

I think I really does not understand but I have some ideas:

a) Using AJAX you can get the response from the remote server and set the innerHTML property of your `<iframe>` or `<div>` with the content obtained.

something like:

```
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp.onReadyState(function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("myiframe").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    });
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "other.site.login/services"); //this is the call for the other site login... you can use POST or GET methods
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("login data");
```

b) You can set the "target" attribute to the `<iframe>` name like `<a href="the.remote.site?login=parameters" target="myiframe">Login</a>` and having obviously an `<iframe id="myiframe">` and it will work for sure.

c) You can format with CSS, and access the content of an `<iframe>` via Javascript, there is a lot documentation about that...

Hope this help you...

Comment: Hi fareden! I think your suggestion is close to what I need. I updated the original post to provide a clear example with pages on my site. Could you take a look and let me know how to make this work? Many thanks!!

Comment: I should have noted... I'm also not sure if this approach will work since the ajax call is being made to a page on a different domain. From what I have seen, browsers will not allow this. The page in the xmlhttp.open("POST", "other.site.login/services") call must be local. I do know that the remote site that I'm dealing with does allow it to be rendered in an Iframe; this is not being restricted.